# PHP How Do I Convert 2 Separate Strings Into An Associative Array (as Index & Value)

Tags: php, arrays, string, indexing, associative-array

I have two string variables:

```
$names = "Sean Connery,George Lazenby,Roger Moore,Timothy Dalton,Pierce,Brosnan,Daniel Craig";
 $movies = "Dr. No/On Her Majesty's Secret Service/Live and Let Die/The Living Daylights/GoldenEye/Casino Royal";
```

I need to convert these two strings into an associative array with `$names` as the `index` and `$movies` as the `values`. How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: you want full $name as index?

Comment: [explode()](http://php.net/explode) comes to mind

Comment: @Dagon In my mind it's more `array_combine()` :)

Comment: @Rizier123 well my mind is only just woke up :-) but array_combine needs arrays not strings, so `explode` first then `array_combine()`

Comment: yes i want all names in the string $names, to be the index, and all movies in the string $movies to be the values. I know how to explode a single string into an array but I can't seem to figure out how to get two separate strings into the same array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with something like this:

```
$array = array_combine(explode(',',$names),explode('/',$movies));
```

Comment: we know where you stole that idea from :-)

Comment: well probably from the php lang ref... but it won't work since his arrays are not the same length

Comment: This worked! how I can be googling for hours & not come across "array_combine" is beyond me, plus the code my teacher gave me to do it is broken. Not working, & it was some pretty complex code compared to this so i couldn't imagine the answer being this simple. This place has saved me yet again.

Comment: This is the code my teacher gave as an example to do it, & she said we'd just have to figure out how to print it: Example:
.<?php
function aexplode($delim,$string,$keys){
    foreach(explode($delim,$string) as $k=>$v){
        $result[$keys[$k]]=$v;
    }
    return $result;
}